# Missing last character while base64 encoding a file from S3 using stream filter

Tags: php, encoding, amazon-s3, base64, php-stream-wrappers

I have a very weird issue with PHP's stream conversion filter ([base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/filters.convert.php)). My goal is to read file from s3 bucket using AWS S3 SDK's streamWrapper and base64 encode it, echo it to response. For this I am using following code,

```
@ob_flush();
@flush();
$fh = fopen(<FILE_PATH>, 'r');
stream_filter_append($fh, 'convert.base64-encode');
fpassthru($fh);
fclose($fh);
```

This works for all types of file, but for a text file it drops last character. When we decode the base64 response, last character is missing.

For example,

`Hello, world!` which encodes to `SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==`

But the above function omits last character while encoding, producing the following

`SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxk` which decodes to `Hello, world`

Any thoughts guys?

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to get this sorted out with AWS Engineers support.

The solution can be found here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/540.

Thanks.